# sqlalchemy and how to count row

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy

I have the following code:

```
query = self.dbObj.session.query(MaterialsTable)
rowCounter = self.dbObj.session.query(MaterialsTable)

for attr , val in interfaceCodesObject.filterNameDict.items():
    query = query.filter(and_(getattr(MaterialsTable,attr).like("%%%s%%" % val)))
    rowCounter = rowCounter.filter(and_(getattr(MaterialsTable,attr).like("%%%s%%" % val))).count()
query.all()
```

When i use mutiple field, i get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mohsen/codes/amlak/amlak/src/ui/materialsFindFrame.py", line 202, in <lambda>
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButtonSearch, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), lambda: self.interfaceCodesConstructor.responseToRequestForData(self))
  File "/home/mohsen/codes/amlak/amlak/src/ui/interface/interface.py", line 109, in responseToRequestForData
    self.materialsObejct.findData(self.objectSearchMaterials,self)
  File "/home/mohsen/codes/amlak/amlak/src/materials/materials.py", line 133, in findData
    rowCounter = rowCounter.filter(and_(getattr(MaterialsTable,attr).like("%%%s%%" % val))).count()
AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

But when i use just one field it use rowCounter as integer and real return.

**My question is** , how can i adapt it with multiple field?Such as : `Where name = 'barak' and id != 3` But one filed such as : `Where name = 'barak'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you just want to get the count of final result? In that case, in fact, you just need only one `query` object instead of both `query` and `rowCounter`.

```
query = self.dbObj.session.query(MaterialsTable)
for attr , val in interfaceCodesObject.filterNameDict.items():
    query = query.filter(and_(getattr(MaterialsTable,attr).like("%%%s%%" % val)))

# all result rows
query.all()

# count of rows
rowCounter = query.count()
```

Hope this helps.